# How to get GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID in google cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gdal

I try to read data from public google cloud storage (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/gcp-public-data-landsat) with Landsat images.

I use for it Python3 with GDAL. 
But I have an error

```
ERROR 15: GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY+GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, GS_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN or GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or GS_OAUTH2_PRIVATE_KEY+GS_OAUTH2_CLIENT_EMAIL configuration options and /home/qwerty/.boto not defined
```

How can I get GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gs_access_key_id` and `gs_secret_access_key` can be generated by

1.navigating to your Google Cloud Storage console and clicking on `Settings`.

2.on the `Settings` page, navigate to the `Interoperability` tab.

3.on this page you can now choose a service account and click `Create a new key` to generate an access key and a matching secret.

Output:

```
New service account HMAC key
service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Access key  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Secret  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Copy this key's secret if you'll need it in the future. Once you close this dialog, the secret can't be recovered.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so well hidden. I tried to find it on the IAM console.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative authentication approach to reading and optionally writing GeoTIF  in GCS.

In CGP Console

- Create a Service Account and download a JSON keyfile. Keep it safe.
- On the Storage Bucket browser, Permission tab, give the new Service Account Roles for:

  - Storage Legacy Bucket Owner and
  - Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
  - path_to_credentials points to your key file

```py
    GEOTIF_PATH = "/vsigs/<my-bucket>/<objectname>"

    with rasterio.Env(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_credentials):
        with rasterio.open('{}'.format(GEOTIF_PATH)) as src:
            print(src.width, src.height)
            profile = src.profile
            print(profile)
```

However, sometimes I am unable to open a file that I think should be openable. Also, if the path is incorrect, like including "gs://" or missing the /vsigs, I get this error:

```
CPLE_NotSupportedError: CPLRSASHA256Sign() not implemented: GDAL must be built against libcrypto++ or libcrypto (openssl)
```

But that can't be right or it wouldn't work at all? However, restarting the jupyter notebook seemed to clear it up.

I am running GDAL 2.3.3, released 2018/12/14, Python 3.7.11 on Windows.